# How do i change the text when i'm submitting

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, dom

I'm not able to change the text at "Enter your age" to "your age is" when submitting. Is there way that when I submit the DOB the "Enter you age" changes to "your age is: X"?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var dobString = document.getElementById("birth_date").value;
  var calculatedValue = calculate_age(dobString);
}

function calculate_age(dobString) {
  var diff_ms = Date.now() - Date.parse(dobString);
  var yearString = "";
  var yearValue = Math.floor(diff_ms / 31536000000);
  console.log("Years ", yearValue);

  if (yearValue > 1) 
    yearString = " years";
  else
    yearString = " year";

  if (yearValue > 0)
    var calculatedValue = yearValue + yearString + " ";
  else if (yearValue == 0)
    var calculatedValue = monthValue + monthString + " ";

  document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = "Your Age is : " + calculatedValue;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Birthday: <input type="date" name="bday" id="birth_date">
  <br><br>
</form>

<button onclick="myFunction()">view</button><br>
<h2>Enter your age</h2>
<p id="age"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update template to be

```
 <h2 id="age">Enter your age</h2>
```

And update script to be like this

```
document.getElementById("age").textContent = "Your Age is : " + calculatedValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate your age a bit differently.
Maybe something like this:

```
function calculate_age(dobString) {
    var birthday = new Date(dobString),  //Year, month, day.
    today = new Date(),
    one_year = 1000*60*60*24*365;
    let yearValue = Math.floor( (today.getTime() - birthday.getTime() ) / one_year);

    let yearString = 'year'
    if (yearValue > 1){ yearString += "s" };

    document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = `Your Age is : ${yearValue} ${yearString}`;
}
```

I created a fiddle for you to see it in action:

https://jsfiddle.net/cdrsfo82/

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, just put `id="age"` on the `<h2>`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var dobString = document.getElementById("birth_date").value;
  var calculatedValue = calculate_age(dobString);
}

function calculate_age(dobString) {
  var diff_ms = Date.now() - Date.parse(dobString);
  var yearString = "";
  var yearValue = Math.floor(diff_ms / 31536000000);
  console.log("Years ", yearValue);

  if (yearValue > 1) 
    yearString = " years";
  else
    yearString = " year";

  if (yearValue > 0)
    var calculatedValue = yearValue + yearString + " ";
  else if (yearValue == 0)
    var calculatedValue = monthValue + monthString + " ";

  document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = "Your Age is : " + calculatedValue;
}
```

```html
<form>
  Birthday: <input type="date" name="bday" id="birth_date">
  <br><br>
</form>

<button onclick="myFunction()">view</button><br>
<h2 id="age">Enter your age</h2>
```

Comment: but the paragraph tag had an id of age.  Just moving it wont solve the issue